# mdframed label multiply defined (with listings and paracol)

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, best-practices, warnings, mdframed

I use three packages (in a latex "book" document) to display source files (not only tex and sometimes loaded from external files) and their outputs (sometimes loaded from external files) side by side.

- listings for the syntax highlighting
- paracol to display side-by-side
- mdframed to customize appearance

My problem is, that this causes warnings of multiply defined labels (somewhere inside mdframed I think):

```
WARNING: Label 'mdf@pagelabel-1' multiply defined
WARNING: There were multiply defined labels
```

I hacked my way through, but I'm not satisfied with my solution... is there a better way?

Here is my minimal "working with warnings" example. My hacks are commented out (to use them toggle comment on the \switchcolumn command to).

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{paracol}

\lstnewenvironment{insertcode}{\mdframed}{\endmdframed}

%-------------------------------------------------------
%\newcounter{mdfzrefhack}
%\setcounter{mdfzrefhack}{1}
%\newcommand{\swcsafe}{
%\switchcolumn
%\setcounter{mdf@zref@counter}{\value{mdfzrefhack}}
%\addtocounter{mdfzrefhack}{1}
%}
%=======================================================

%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{insertcode}
x
\end{insertcode}

%-------------------------------------------------------
%\swcsafe
%=======================================================
\switchcolumn
%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{insertcode}
y
\end{insertcode}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Each of the modifications below (magically in some cases) make the warnings go away:

- not using mdframed
- changing the document type from book to minimal (for ex.)
- shifting one of the listings a bit lower by placing some text above it in the column

Edited: made the example simpler, deleted PS (thanks to [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg))

UPDATE: I've just [submitted](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed/issues/15) this on the github of `mdframed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Official* answer from the `mdframed` package author and maintainer:

> In your question you pointed out the correct issue. I think the simplest way is to use the option `usetwoside=false`:

`\lstnewenvironment{insertcode}{\mdframed[usetwoside=false]}{\endmdframed}`

> In this case no check is done.

Comment: Did it help?  ...

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It seems to help.

Comment: This also worked to fix "undefined reference" warnings that were also caused by the mdframed package.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the “internal” commands in `\lstnewenvironment`, instead of `\begin{mdframed}` and `\end{mdframed}`. This seems to work:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{paracol}

\lstnewenvironment{insertcode}{\mdframed}{\endmdframed}

\newcounter{mdfzrefhack}
\setcounter{mdfzrefhack}{1}
\newcommand{\swcsafe}{\switchcolumn
  \setcounter{mdf@zref@counter}{\value{mdfzrefhack}}%
  \addtocounter{mdfzrefhack}{1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{insertcode}
x
\end{insertcode}

\swcsafe

\begin{insertcode}
y
\end{insertcode}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd probably say

```
\lstnewenvironment{insertcode}[1][]
  {\lstset{#1}\mdframed}
  {\endmdframed}
```

so that additional `listings` options to `insertcode` can be set.

Comment: Thanks, but this only answers my "PS", not the original question. Still it was a helpful info, but the problem stays. I'll edit my code according to your suggestion to leave out \Before... commands.
And of course, I use a more complicated logic inside insertcode, but It was a minimal example so...