# Two Columns of Text Side by Side

Tags: two-column

First let me just point out that I am new to LaTeX and I searched for an answer to the question but I could not find anything I could use. So if you already know where I can find my answer just point me in the direction and I will remove this thread.

Now, I have a problem getting two examples of text next to each other. It is an example of a template and I would like to show two variants side by side. This is the text:

```
openstack {  
    tenant <some name>  
    image <image name>  
    flavor <flavor type>  
    keypair <keypair>  
}  
 network eth0 {  
        net <net>  
    }  
}  
host <hostname> {  
    superclass common  
    network eth0 {  
           floating-ip auto ext_net  
    }  
}
```

Does anyone know how I could do this is in a neat fashion?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)
You may want to check [my question from last month](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133712/using-lstlistings-in-two-columns). Possible duplicate?!

Comment: Use two minipages. If they have widths that total less than the current line width, and there is no blank line between them, they will be side-by side.

Answer (score 7):

You can find very useful stuff about multi-column pages at the LaTeX Wiki:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Multi-column_pages

In short, you can use the code below for a two-column text:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
lots of text
\end{multicols}
```

Just don't forget to add

```
\usepackage{multicol}
```

at the preamble of your code.

Good Luck :)

Comment: You're welcome @Jonas. You may accept this answer as accepted, if it helped you.