# Multiple listings in one box with sub captions and using listings counter

Tags: listings, captions, subfloats

I am using separate counters for (graphics) figures and listings. I am using the `caption` and `subcaption` packages. I construct sub-figures using `subfigure`:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.34\textwidth}
...
\caption{sub-1}\label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.34\textwidth}
...
\caption{sub-2}\label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Now I need the same construction for listings. Like

```
\newsavebox{\verbsavebox}

\begin{figure}
\begin{lrbox}{\verbsavebox}
\begin{minipage}{.34\textwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}
...
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.34\textwidth}
\usebox{\verbsavebox}
\caption{sub-1}\label{lst:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{lrbox}{\verbsavebox}
\begin{minipage}{.34\textwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}
...
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.34\textwidth}
\usebox{\verbsavebox}
\caption{sub-2}\label{lst:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that this uses the figure counter, and the main caption is named "Fig...". What I want is use the listings counter and have the main caption named "Listing...".

---

**EDIT** Here is another try using `lstlisting`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[scaled=.73]{beramono}
\fvset{baselinestretch=0.94}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip = 6pt

% "define" Scala
\lstdefinelanguage{scala}{
  morekeywords={abstract,case,catch,class,def,%
    do,else,extends,false,final,finally,%
    for,if,implicit,import,match,mixin,%
    new,null,object,override,package,%
    private,protected,requires,return,sealed,%
    super,this,throw,trait,true,try,%
    type,val,var,while,with,yield,then}, % we use `then` in the pseudocode
  otherkeywords={=>,<-,<\%,<:,>:,\#,@},
  sensitive=true,
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"""
}

% activate the language and predefine settings
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.94}\ttfamily,%
    language=scala,%
    commentstyle=\itshape,%
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,%
    fancyvrb=true,%
    mathescape=true,%  for pseudocode
    captionpos=b, % captions at the bottom
}

\begin{document}

In Fig.~\ref{fig:label} versus Listings~\ref{lst:label1} and \ref{lst:label2}.

\begin{figure}
Empty
\caption{fig}\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure} % [htp]
\begin{lstlisting}{caption={list1},label={lst:label1}}
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type ID <: Ident[S#Tx]
  type Tx
}

trait Muta[S <: Sys[S]] {
  def id: S#ID
  // well defined:
  def dispose(tx: S#Tx) =
    id.dispose(tx)
}

trait Ident[Tx] {
  def dispose(tx: Tx): Unit
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}{caption={list2},label={lst:label2}}
trait Sys {
  type ID <: Ident[Tx]
  type Tx
}

trait Muta[S <: Sys] {
  def id: S#ID   
  // incompatible type:
  def dispose(tx: S#Tx) =
    id.dispose(tx)
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}{caption={list3},label={lst:label3}}
trait Sys {
  type ID <: Ident[Tx]
  type Tx
}

trait Muta[S <: Sys] {
  // evidence required:
  val s: S
  def id: s.ID
  // well defined:
  def dispose(tx: s.Tx) =
    id.dispose(tx)
}
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{Total caption}\label{lst:total}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The problem is, the listings box gets numbered "Figure 2" instead of "Listing 1", and there are no sub captions (a) (b) (c). The reference in the text is broken, too. And the three listings should appear in three columns next to each other. So this is how the preceding code looks:

[image]

And this is a mock up of how it *should* look:

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

Ok, so I [compiled paracol.sty](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/paracol) and tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[scaled=.73]{beramono}
\fvset{baselinestretch=0.94}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip = 6pt
\usepackage{caption}

% "define" Scala
\lstdefinelanguage{scala}{
  morekeywords={abstract,case,catch,class,def,%
    do,else,extends,false,final,finally,%
    for,if,implicit,import,match,mixin,%
    new,null,object,override,package,%
    private,protected,requires,return,sealed,%
    super,this,throw,trait,true,try,%
    type,val,var,while,with,yield,then}, % we use `then` in the pseudocode
  otherkeywords={=>,<-,<\%,<:,>:,\#,@},
  sensitive=true,
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"""
}

% activate the language and predefine settings
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.94}\ttfamily,%
    language=scala,%
    commentstyle=\itshape,%
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,%
    fancyvrb=true,%
    mathescape=true,%  for pseudocode
    captionpos=b, % captions at the bottom
}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

In Fig.~\ref{fig:label} versus Listings~\ref{lst:label1} and \ref{lst:label2}.

\begin{paracol}{3}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={list1},label={lst:label1}]
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type ID <: Ident[S#Tx]
  type Tx
}

trait Muta[S <: Sys[S]] {
  def id: S#ID
  // well defined:
  def dispose(tx: S#Tx) =
    id.dispose(tx)
}

trait Ident[Tx] {
  def dispose(tx: Tx): Unit
}
\end{lstlisting}
\switchcolumn
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={list2},label={lst:label2}]
trait Sys {
  type ID <: Ident[Tx]
  type Tx
}

trait Muta[S <: Sys] {
  def id: S#ID   
  // incompatible type:
  def dispose(tx: S#Tx) =
    id.dispose(tx)
}
\end{lstlisting}
\switchcolumn
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={list3},label={lst:label3}]
trait Sys {
  type ID <: Ident[Tx]
  type Tx
}

trait Muta[S <: Sys] {
  // evidence required:
  val s: S
  def id: s.ID
  // well defined:
  def dispose(tx: s.Tx) =
    id.dispose(tx)
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{paracol}

\begin{figure}
Empty
\caption{fig}\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This produces three identical caption numbers and not 1a, 1b, 1c:

[image]

Comment: Note: I cannot use `subfloat` because the cross references with it are broken, I have to use `subfigure`.

Comment: Why do you refer to `Verbatim` as `listings`? If you use the `listings` package, there are `caption` and `label` options and they will be labeled as "Listings" instead of figures.

Comment: There was a reason I had use savebox and minipages, something didn't work with `\begin{lstlistings}`, I think it had to do with the impossibility of putting three columns next to each other?

Comment: Why would it be impossible to put 3 columns next to each other? It is even [possible with the use of `listings`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133712/using-lstlistings-in-two-columns).

Comment: @masu See my edit. The problem is the captions and numbering.

Comment: I've had a similar problem. The solution for me was an `mdframed` box and the `afterlastframe` and `aftersingleframe` options with a custom counter. This approach has a design flaw in pagebreaking which I [tried to get a solution for](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140314/how-to-undo-the-feasible-breakpoints-of-lstlisting).

Comment: If pagebreaking is not necessary, you can put this in a custom float which you can caption as you like.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

The following should be right up your allow. It's achieved with the aid of [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) and some manual float management:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,listings,caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage[scaled=.73]{beramono}
\fvset{baselinestretch=0.94}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip = 6pt

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareCaptionSubType{lstlisting}
\renewcommand{\p@sublstlisting}{\thelstlisting}
\renewcommand{\thesublstlisting}{(\alph{sublstlisting})}
}
\makeatother
% "define" Scala
\lstdefinelanguage{scala}{
  morekeywords={abstract,case,catch,class,def,%
    do,else,extends,false,final,finally,%
    for,if,implicit,import,match,mixin,%
    new,null,object,override,package,%
    private,protected,requires,return,sealed,%
    super,this,throw,trait,true,try,%
    type,val,var,while,with,yield,then}, % we use `then` in the pseudocode
  otherkeywords={=>,<-,<\%,<:,>:,\#,@},
  sensitive=true,
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"""
}

% activate the language and predefine settings
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.94}\ttfamily,%
    language=scala,%
    commentstyle=\itshape,%
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,%
    fancyvrb=true,%
    mathescape=true,%  for pseudocode
    captionpos=b, % captions at the bottom
}
\newsavebox{\verbsavebox}
\begin{document}

In Fig.~\ref{fig:label} versus Listings~\ref{lst:label1} and \ref{lst:label2}.

\begin{figure}
Empty
\caption{fig}\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure} % [htp]
% Let's make this an lstlisting, not a figure...
\makeatletter\def\@captype{lstlisting}\makeatother
\begin{lrbox}{\verbsavebox}
\begin{lstlisting}[xrightmargin=.6667\linewidth]
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type ID <: Ident[S#Tx]
  type Tx
}

trait Muta[S <: Sys[S]] {
  def id: S#ID
  // well defined:
  def dispose(tx: S#Tx) =
    id.dispose(tx)
}

trait Ident[Tx] {
  def dispose(tx: Tx): Unit
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}
\subcaptionbox{list1\label{lst:label1}}{\usebox{\verbsavebox}}\hfill%
\begin{lrbox}{\verbsavebox}
\begin{lstlisting}[xrightmargin=.6667\linewidth]
trait Sys {
  type ID <: Ident[Tx]
  type Tx
}

trait Muta[S <: Sys] {
  def id: S#ID   
  // incompatible type:
  def dispose(tx: S#Tx) =
    id.dispose(tx)
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}
\subcaptionbox{list2\label{lst:label2}}{\usebox{\verbsavebox}}\hfill%
\begin{lrbox}{\verbsavebox}
\begin{lstlisting}[xrightmargin=.6667\linewidth]
trait Sys {
  type ID <: Ident[Tx]
  type Tx
}

trait Muta[S <: Sys] {
  // evidence required:
  val s: S
  def id: s.ID
  // well defined:
  def dispose(tx: s.Tx) =
    id.dispose(tx)
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}
\subcaptionbox{list3\label{lst:label3}}{\usebox{\verbsavebox}}
\caption{Total caption\label{lst:total}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Each of the listings are set in a box `\verbsavebox` of width `.3333\linewidth` (by setting `xrightmargin=.6667\linewidth`). These boxes, once set, are added using `\subcaptionbox{<caption>}{\usebox{\verbsavebox}}`, where `<caption>` includes both the caption and the `\label`.

Immediately inside the `figure` environment, we strategically update the `\@captype` to be `lstlisting`. This fools TeX to think that it's dealing with a float called `lstlisting` when you call `\caption`. This is necessary since the `\subcaption`s are set *before* the main `\caption`, which requires `\p@lstlisting` (the parent counter associated with the subcounter `sublstlisting`) to be set correctly. This is all related to the functionality of the `subcaption` package.

The subcaptions are defined `\AtBeginDocument`, which is to coincide with the float definitions of [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings), which is done at the same time. `subcaption` requires a float to exist before it allows one to define subcaptions for it.