# One page caption one page picture

Tags: diagrams

I'm searching for a way to create a book of figures as next:

left pages contains captions of the images in right pages

|  caption  ||  image    |

and if two images are in one page at right, I want two captions at left at the same height, and so forth.

Thank you

Comment: Check out the answer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14647/multipages-side-by-side-listings